# Assembly name adds Directory name as prefix when Publishing a build using MSBuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-assembly, publishing

I was trying to publish a solution (created in visual studio) using MSBuild in command Line.
But the assembly files that i am getting are named with Folders in which they are saved as the prefix.

ex. if i am publishing the build in a folder named "SIT" and assembly name is "FWA" then after build has published the application files are named SITFWA.application.

the command that i am using in command line to publish the build is:

> > msbuild /t:publish /p:PublishDir="C:\User\Desktop\wert\SIT"

Comment: Hi, please check if my answer helps you handle the issue or not, and let us know if it helps or not. And it is kind of you to do that to create a good stack overflow community atmosphere.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should note that the `PublishDir` node is identified as the folder path. So you must add `\`.

And if you use `/p:PublishDir="C:\User\Desktop\wert\SIT"`, it means that `SIT` is a part of the assembly name.

**Solution**

So you should use this publish command:

```
msbuild /t:publish /p:PublishDir="C:\User\Desktop\wert\SIT\"
```

Comment: thanks perry but i am getting errors while publishing after putting"\" at the end

Comment: And did you publish a winform project? In my side, I used that publish command without any errors, so share your error message with us to help us troubleshoot the issue:)

Comment: @anshumanpandey ,Any update about this issue? And we are willing to help you further:)

Comment: yeah i used build.csproj to provide properties and the published files are saved in debug folder inside the project folder without any prefix